# DocuSign - How to get a URL that lasts longer than a few minutes?

Tags: docusignapi

I am using the DocuSign REST Api and noticed that the lifetime of a URL obtained using the EnvelopeViews API (https://developers.docusign.com/esign-rest-api/reference/Envelopes/EnvelopeViews/createRecipient) is only a few minutes. However, I have gotten emails in the past with DocuSign links. How are these links able to be added to an email (and therefore have a longer lifetime)?

Is there a separate API that can be used to get a longer-life link like the one in the email?

For example, here is an email that has a *Review Document* DocuSign link:
[image]

Answer (score 2):

Good question. Here's what you can do.

1. Your application wants to let Larry sign a document using the 
   EnvelopeViews::createRecipient API call.
2. Your application should store the details needed for the API call in your app's database. Something like: envelopeId, signerEmail, clientUserId.
3. Create a guid for the database record and add it to the database record.
4. Now you can look up the database record via either the row's key or
   via the guid. Ensure that the guid database column is indexed.
5. Now create a signing url that you will send to Larry. Something like:

   https://myapplication.example.com/docusign-ceremony/[guid]
6. Send the url to Larry
7. When Larry clicks on the URL:

   1. Your app is invoked
   2. Look up the guid in the url in your database. You should find the
      record that you stored there.
   3. Retrieve all of the record's info: envelopeId, signerEmail, 
      clientUserId.
   4. Call the EnvelopeViews::createRecipient API call with the data
      and get back the signing ceremony url (that must be used within 
      5 minutes)
   5. Redirect the user's browser to the url.
   6. They'll sign the document(s) and then be re-directed back to your
      application.
   7. Done.

And guess what? This is pretty much what DocuSign does itself.

Comment: This strategy makes sense. However (and I probably wasn't clear in my question), I was wondering that if DocuSign implements this strategy themselves, why can't they provide that functionality to me instead of making me re-implement the strategy? This is a significant amount of development/testing/maintenance effort that I don't want to use unless I have to.

Comment: The RecipientView methnod is intended to enable an application to add an **embedded** signing ceremony to the app. You're asking to have the ability to send a url by email that will be turned into a signing ceremony. That's a different use case and is not a primary use case for DocuSign. So at this time, if you want that feature you'll need to develop it yourself as described in the answer. If you have DocuSign send out the email with the url in it then you do not need to develop anything. And remember that you can change the email that DocuSign sends out via the branding feature.

Comment: This is spot on. Thanks for confirming.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

The response from Larry K above is correct, you would need to handle this on your side.

These are all the parameters that you can send as part of the request body for the POST {vx}/accounts/{accountid}/envelopes/{envelopeid}/views/recipient API endpoint and there are no options to set the expiration time for the recipient view that you create.

You could look into using PowerForms to see if they fit your needs. With PowerForms you can create a URL that users can click and it will allow them to fill out a specific DocuSign envelope. This might not fit your needs if you need to pre-fill some of the fields with information related to the specific recipient but it might be worth looking at.

PowerForms Documentation:
https://www.docusign.com/features-and-benefits/features/powerforms

Answer (score 0):

Please correct me if I'm wrong but I think that your goal is creating the recipient view URL, creating an email formatted in a specific way and sending that email to the recipients.

If you use the branding feature you could specify the format for your email (if you want to use a specific message) and just send the envelope to your recipients. Once the recipients receive the email they'll see the message in the format that you specified and the link for accessing the envelope would be a regular DocuSign link that doesn't expire.

The link below shows how to create Brands in your account. Specifically signing brands would allow you to set the email content.

If you have multiple email formats you could create multiple brands and just specify the brandId when creating the envelope.

I hope this helps.

Branding:
https://support.docusign.com/guides/ndse-admin-guide-configure-branding